# Emberjs populate a Ember dropdown box from an ArrayController

Tags: javascript, api, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I am having trouble populating an Ember [dropdown box](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html) with data retrieved from my backend.

For the sake of this example, let us say that I have a dropdown with a list of cars. I want the user to be able to choose a car. I want this dropdown to be populated by ember rest adapter by going to `/cars` and storing the return data in an arraycontroller.

Examples/solutions?

Comment: updated my answer, have a look. you will see that it fetches the same model two times, but it could be any model...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eqohah/1/edit) I hacked togheter using the [apiary.io](http://apiary.io/) API.

It's fairly simple but it works the way you want.

Hope it helps.

**Update**

See this modified [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/owebex/1/edit) on how you might use the same route with multiple models.

**Update 2**

Since ember's newest releases (ember 1.0.0, ember data 1.0.0 beta) many things have changed, [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/usOfICO/3/edit) is the updated version.

Comment: It works. But what if I have multiple select boxes? A route can only have one model..:(

Comment: @joelcox, updated my answer, now it should work again, hope it helps.

Comment: Great, just wanted to let you know.